# undefined is not a function - error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

```
timechart = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('timechart'));
```

I get the `undefined is not a function on this line`. I have other charts initialized on the same page and they work fine. For reference, the rest of my relevant code:

```
var timechartGraph = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
 'chartType': 'LineChart',
 'containerId': 'timechart-graph',
 'options': {
   // Use the same chart area width as the control for axis alignment.
  'legend': {'position': 'right'}

 },
 // Convert the first column from 'date' to 'string'.
 'view': {
   'columns': [
      {
       'calc': function(dataTable, rowIndex) {
         return dataTable.getFormattedValue(rowIndex, 11);
       },
       'type': 'string'
     },1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
 }
 });

  var timechartRangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
 'controlType': 'ChartRangeFilter',
 'containerId': 'timechart-range-slider',
 'options': {
   // Filter by the date axis.
   'filterColumnIndex': 11,
   'ui': {
     'chartType': 'LineChart',
     'chartOptions': {
       'hAxis': {'baselineColor': 'none'}
     },
     // Display a single series that shows the closing value of the stock.
     // Thus, this view has two columns: the date (axis) and the stock value (line series).
     'chartView': {
       'columns': [11, 12]
     },
     // 1 day in milliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 86,400,000
     //'minRangeSize': 86400000
   }
 },
 // Initial range: 2012-02-09 to 2012-03-20.
 //'state': {'range': {'start': new Date(2012, 1, 9), 'end': new Date(2012, 2, 20)}}
});

timechartData = new google.visualization.DataTable();

timechart = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('timechart'));
timechart.bind(timechartRangeSlider, timechartGraph);
```

Comment: print out `google`, `google.visualization`, `google.visualization.Dashboard` and `document.getElementById('timechart')` to see which one is undefined.

Comment: Did you load the "controls" package?  The Dashboard object requires the controls package to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading just corechart right now, you're code probably looks something like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
```

You have to load the controls package as well, like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'controls']
});
```

And that should make google.visualization.Dashboard defined.

Comment: i faced a similar error   **a is not a function** ...but the solution you suggested did not solve it for me.

`google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["bar", "controls"]});`